# visual c++ 2010 internal error with boost::multi_index?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boost

I'm using boost::multi_index with visual studio 2010, and it seems to crash when used with boost::const_mem_fun and virtual class methods :

```
class Node
{
public:
    virtual const std::string& getValue() const {return m_strValue;}

protected:
    std::string m_strValue;

private:
    struct byValue{};
    typedef boost::multi_index_container<
     boost::shared_ptr<Node>,
     boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
      boost::multi_index::random_access<>,
      boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<
       boost::multi_index::tag<byValue>,
       boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<Node, const std::string& , &Node::getValue>
      >
     >
    > NodeList;
};
```

when compiling this, visual crash with this kind of message :

```
fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1> (compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1420)
1> To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
1> Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++ 
1> Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
```

but if Node::getValue isn't virtual, the compilation is ok.
is there a way to go around this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this compiler bug by using a [user-defined key extractor](http://live.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/key_extraction.html#user_defined_key_extractors):

```
class Node
{
public:
    virtual const std::string& getValue() const {return m_strValue;}

protected:
    std::string m_strValue;

private:
    struct KeyExtractor
    {
      typedef std::string result_type;

      const result_type& operator()(const boost::shared_ptr<Node>& p) const
      {
          return p->getValue();
      }        
    };

    struct byValue{};

    typedef boost::multi_index_container<
     boost::shared_ptr<Node>,
     boost::multi_index::indexed_by<
      boost::multi_index::random_access<>,
      boost::multi_index::ordered_non_unique<
       boost::multi_index::tag<byValue>,
       KeyExtractor
      >
     >
    > NodeList;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Report the bug to Microsoft.

No matter how weird the code is, the compiler should not crash.